# Delete current parent node in recursion

Tags: javascript, html

I created multiple divs which `class="extra"`. Then I add delete buttons to each div in order to remove each div respectively. So my code is:

```
  var exr = document.getElementsByClassName("extra");           
    for(var i = 0 ;i<exr.length;i++){         
        var delbt = document.createElement("button");
        delbt.className="floatbutton_3 font_b"
        delbt.innerHTML="delete";
        exr[i].appendChild(delbt);
        delbt.onclick=  function(i){ return function(){ exr[i].parentNode.removeChild(exr[i]) } }(i);
   }
```

The problem is, the button can't removethe button it should remove. It seems that after last delete, the index is changed. How to avoid this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery if you don't use it? Do you intend to use jQuery?

Comment: You are iterating over `inserter`, while accessing `exr`, and modifying a nodeList __does__ change the index. iterate the opposite way.

Comment: try downwards, eg `for(var i=exr.length;i>0;i--){ `

Comment: @Felix Kling I mean jquery is also acceptable to make modification

Comment: And what is `inserter` ?

Comment: @adeneo sorry..now I correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` within the `onclick` function to reference the button that was clicked — so by replacing `excr[i]` with `this.parentNode`, your code should execute as intended.

Comment: *"The problem is that within the function, `i` is the argument that refers to the click event."* No, it's an IIFE. Have a look at the code again.

Comment: Weird… Was that an edit? In any case, the technical points remain: `i` is not the thing to look for (and it's confusing, since that's also the index from the iterator further up the scope). Meanwhile, `this` will be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The code *looks* like it should work, but only as long as you don't add or remove elements. And that's what you are doing.

There is a simpler and more reliable solution: You can use `this` inside the event handler to refer to the current element.

```
delbt.onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentNode; // you want to remove the div, not the button
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
};
```

---

I recommend to read [the excellent articles about event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) on quirksmode.org, especially about [traditional event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) (since that's what you are using).

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

```
var exr = document.getElementsByClassName("extra");           
for(var i = 0 ;i<inserter.length;i++){         
    var delbt = document.createElement("button");
    delbt.className="floatbutton_3 font_b"
    delbt.innerHTML="delete";
    exr[i].appendChild(delbt);
    delbt.index = i;
    delbt.onclick=  function(i){ var me = this; return function(){ exr[me.index].parentNode.removeChild(exr[i])    } }(i);
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. In your code, `this` refers to `window` not the DOM element.

Comment: Oops... sorry... mixed jQuery and regular JS here. My Bad... So you could say `var me = (event || window.event).target;` instead of `var me = this;`

Comment: That won't work either and has nothing to do with jQuery. That's an IIFE, i.e. the function is executed **immediately**. The function *returned* by that function is the event handler, and there `this` would refer to the element and `event` would be available.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a jQuery solution:

```
$('.extra').append(function() {
    return $('<button />', {'class':'floatbutton_3 font_b', html:'delete'});
});

$('.floatbutton_3').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GrDBz/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Since `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live set, you could make a shallow copy first:

```
var exr = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("extra"), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection. This is a live list that changes when the underlying structure changes. So even if you don't activly delete the elements from the list, they still will be removed from it automatically when you remove the corresponding HTML Element.

By passing `i` to the anonymous function, you kind of fixed the index. So whenever you click on the third delete button it will try to delete the third element in the list. But if you have already deleted the first and the second element, the list will be modified too. So your third button will be represented by the first item in your list but it will try to find the third one.

To avoid this problem you can pass the complete element to the anonymous function and not just the index:

```
for(var i = 0 ;i<exr.length;i++){         
    var delbt = document.createElement("button");
    delbt.className="floatbutton_3 font_b"
    delbt.innerHTML="delete";
    exr[i].appendChild(delbt);
    delbt.onclick = function(el){ return function(){ el.parentNode.removeChild(el) } }(exr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use currentTarget on the click event.

This will only remove the parent div of the button clicked.

```
var exr = document.getElementsByClassName("extra");
for(var i = 0 ;i<exr.length;i++){
    var delbt = document.createElement("button");
    delbt.className="floatbutton_3 font_b"
    delbt.innerHTML="delete";
    exr[i].appendChild(delbt);
    delbt.onclick=  function( event ){
        event.currentTarget.parentElement.remove();
    }
}
```